# Code visualisation api for .NET/Windows

Tags: visualization

Is there an organic code visualisation which works for .NET/Windows just like Gourge (sp?)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best tool that I know of is [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/).

Can't find Gourge, sorry.